# Need a help in design approach in android app

Tags: android

i’m developing app for school management where their are three different menus principal,teacher,student .

here i had done it by keeping all screens and code  in one app and displaying respective screens according to login details.by this size of app increased and when teacher is login he don’t want the screens of principal and student.

is this a correct  way to represent respective screens by using login details or is their another approach like downloading java project form server based on login details?

Comment: What about having 3 different apps?

Comment: Take a look at flavors in studio.. may be you can find a soluion

Answer (score 0):

You should be developing 3 different apps.

Mobiles are personal devices so a student will not be using teachers module at any given point of time. and same goes for other roles as well.

Comment: But acc to my requirement i should make it in one app where if teacher logins  initially remaining two modules should be delete stuff like that.

Comment: you can not delete modules from your app binary at runtime. you have to take care of this at build time itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide an option for selecting the user at starting screen and proceed with the screens for the selected user.Eg.If user is a teacher,you can show login screen for teacher and likewise

Answer (score 0):

Honestly I'm not sure this question belongs to SO.
If anything this is purely a matter of opinion;

If the authentication process itself is secure enough and the methods it used are also safe, it should be no problem to have them all in one app.